# How to find minimum value in a collection using linq?

Tags: c#

I have a collection where i need to find an item with lowest price if more than 1 found the by default any should be selected and it's isPriceSelected property need to set false.

I am trying something like this.

```
lstBtn.Where(p => p.CategoryID == btnObj.CategoryID && 
                  p.IsSelected == true && p.IsPriceApplied == true)
      .ToList()
      .Min(m=>m.Price)
```

Comment: Why you want use Linq? Just simply do this: myList.Sort(); then select the first element of the list

Comment: @Tinwor: because his requirement is to get the minimum price, not to sort the original collection. Apart from that, `lstBtn.Sort` would not sort by `Price` automatically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just the select the property that you want the minimum from:

```
var minimumPrice = lstBtn
   .Where(p => p.CategoryID == btnObj.CategoryID && p.IsSelected && p.IsPriceApplied)
   .Min(p => p.Price);
```

If you actually want to find the item with the lowest price you need to order the collection:

```
var itemWithMinimumPrice = lstBtn
   .OrderBy(p => p.Price)
   .FirstOrDefault(p => p.CategoryID == btnObj.CategoryID && p.IsSelected && p.IsPriceApplied);
```

or this, could be more efficient:

```
var itemWithMinimumPrice = lstBtn
   .Where(p => p.CategoryID == btnObj.CategoryID && p.IsSelected && p.IsPriceApplied)
   .OrderBy(p => p.Price)
   .FirstOrDefault();
```

`Enumerable.FirstOrDefault` returns one item or `null` if no item matches the predicate.

Comment: Curious minds want to know, could this also be `lstBtn.Min(p => p.CategoryID == btnObj.CategoryID && p.IsSelected && p.IsPriceApplied);`?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: That returns `false` if there is at least one item that does not match this predicate, otherwise true(since true is "higher" than false). But it's obviously not what OP wants

Comment: okay so I'd have to return the actual value if I wanted to inline the condition like that; in effect gaining nothing really because it's much more readable and just as efficient with the `Where`, right?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: I must admit that i don't understand your last comment. `Min` is used to return a minimum value, `Where` is used to restrict the items used to calculate the min-value, so both are needed. It helps to "translate" the `Where` to an `if`-statement (so not an additional loop or method).

Comment: it wil return the minimum price itself or the object whose property i can reset to false

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet: It returns the minimumprice. Have you edited your answer? Now it's obvious that you want the item with the lowest price, not only the price. Then you need to order all items first. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, it's cool. I think I'm rambling a bit and should just grab another cup of coffee! :D - you know you always have my vote!

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
var result = lstBtn
    .Where(p => p.CategoryID == btnObj.CategoryID && p.IsSelected && p.IsPriceApplied)
    .OrderBy(p => p.Price)
    .First();
```

This will first find all items which have the specified `CategoryID`, `IsSelected`, and `IsPriceApplied` all set to true, then sort items by `Price`, and return the first item with the lowest price.

Comment: How can i set isPriceApplied to false in the same statement.

Comment: The best option is to do it in a second statement `result.IsPriceApplied = false`

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, linq can only return the actual value with Min and Max methods.
You can use a good project morelinq https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview
It has the method you need. For myself, I find this project having too many methods, so I simply cut and paste only needed from its sources.
With morelinq your code should look like:

```
lstBtn.Where(p => p.CategoryID == btnObj.CategoryID && p.IsSelected == true && p.IsPriceApplied==true).MinBy(m=>m.Price)
```

Another approach, if you also need to get all duplicates:

```
var lowestPriceProducts = lstBtn.Where(p => p.CategoryID == btnObj.CategoryID)
    .GroupBy(p => p.Price, new { p.Price, Product = p})
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Price)
    .First()
    .Select(x => x.Product)
    .ToList()
```

This query will return you a list (with only one item if there are no duplicate prices) of products with minimal price. Then you can do anything with it.